# Change doctrine array type from tinytext to longtext

Tags: arrays, symfony, doctrine

I have a problem with the doctrine array type,
I have a field containing various data mostly strings that I need under the array form.

```
 /**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="data", type="array", length=250, nullable=false,
 *      options={"comment" = "Data of notification."})
 */
protected $data;
```

But I noticed that it is stored under the tinytext form in MySQL which is way to short to store the data I want
Does anyone now how I can force doctrine to switch from tinytext to longtext?

Comment: You should remove the `length=250,`  part

Answer (score 4):

Increase length.

> array [1] array   MySQL   all TINYTEXT [17] TEXT [18]
> MEDIUMTEXT [19] LONGTEXT [20]
>
> - [17]    (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) Chosen if the column length is less or equal to 2 ^ 8 - 1 = 255.
> - [18]    (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) Chosen if the column length is less or equal to 2 ^ 16 - 1 = 65535.
> - [19]    (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) Chosen if the column length is less or equal to 2 ^ 24 - 1 = 16777215.
> - [20]    (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) Chosen if the column length is less or equal to 2 ^ 32 - 1 = 4294967295 or empty.

source:
http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/types.html#mapping-matrix

Answer (score 0):

Please check this session:
http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/types.html#string

Check the other types in the manual as well, array as you wish!

> Database vendors have different limits for the maximum length of a varying string. Doctrine internally maps the string type to the vendor’s text type if the maximum allowed length is exceeded. This can lead to type inconsistencies when reverse engineering the type from the database.

Which means you have to raise the length of your column if you want to force a bigger size.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like the field to map to a LONGTEXT column then use:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="data", type="array", length=16777216, nullable=false,
 *      options={"comment" = "Data of notification."})
 */
protected $data;
```

i.e. by setting length to a value above 16777215 you will map the field to a LONGTEXT.

You can also omit the length parameter (it is usually used to hint Doctrine to use a field type smaller than LONGTEXT). E.g. if you set length to 1000 you will get a TEXT field, or if you set a number less than 255 you will get a TINYTEXT field (as you have already discovered).

Comment: 16777216 is for `MEDIUMTEXT`, for `LONGTEXT` you need 4294967295